How to include custom theme and styles into build Angular AND import it after build
I have Angular 17 app (let call it Child) which I build into js-file and after use in other application (Parent). Parent application has own theme and styles. But in Child-app I use custom styles and theme. How can I include it in build and when Parent-app loads Child-app - use it (import) without adding to global styles, so get it from directly from js-file
I have tried a lot of variants but no one matched my expectations.
